# Resque and redis server not playing well with each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, redis, resque

I have install the redis server using these commands,

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
make test # to test everything is working out well or not
```

after this I navigate to the redis-stable directory to start redis server using

```
src/redis-server
```

now if I have rails app running and I try to visit localhost:3000/resque it is working with no errors ,

But when I try to stop( I am using cntrl+c to stop the running server) and start again using src/redis-server it is throwing an exception like this

```
 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
    [10020] 16 May 13:30:31 # Opening port 6379: bind: Address already in use
```

from this I infer that the redis server is already running but when I visit localhost:3000/resque I am getting this error

```
Errno::EAGAIN at /resque/overview
Resource temporarily unavailable - Timeout reading from the socket
```

currently I am restarting my ubuntu system in order to solve this
any ideas how to solve this ?

Thanks for Reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you are closing it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and not just pausing it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>? From what you write you have already something bound to port 6379, something which doesn't react to connections (hence my idea that you are using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> in fact). Next time when it will happen to you, try to run `netstat -tlnp` you will see which process has bound port 6379 so you will be able to kill it.

Comment: yeps I think I was pausing It rather than killing how stupid of me!